# Change UINavigationBar button image

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to replace the image displayed in my right navigation bar button when it is tapped.

At the moment what seems to be happening is that it is not replacing the button, but trying to set it while the old one still exists. This leads to a strange effect as you can see:

[image]

It's a compass image, so there should only be one circle, but as you can see three are appearing.

This is my code:

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Compass.png")!
navButton.setBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

Is there a way to remove the existing one and replace it with the new one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like perhaps you are setting the UIBarButtonItem's `backgroundImage` when what you really want to set is its `image`. Thus you end up seeing both of them.

Comment: Ah! It seems obvious now, but I wasn't aware that they were separate. Thanks a lot! I'll accept when it allows me to.